# Trying to understand why "long blocks between primes" must exist

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm currently going through "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" by Hardy and Wright and at one point, they discuss why the distance from one prime to the next must have a long chunk of composites in between. I'm trying to understand the reasoning but I'm having some difficulty. Here is what they say:

> Suppose that $2, 3, \ldots, p$ are the primes upto $p$. Then all the numbers up to $p$ are divisible by one of these primes, and therefore, if $2\cdot3\cdot5 \cdots p = q$ all of the $p-1$ numbers i.e. $q + 2, q+3, q+4 \ldots , q+p$ are composite.

I'm having particular difficulty understanding the $q + 2, q+3, q+4, \ldots , q+p$ part. If $q$ is equal to the product of primes from $2$ to $p$ then how can how can we have all the $p-1$ numbers be equal to $q+2, q+3, q+4, \ldots q + p$?

Can someone please clarify this? or if not, just explain what they are trying to say here.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: q+2 is divisible by 2, q+3 is divisible by 3, q+4 is divisible by 2 again, q+5 is divisible by 5,....

Comment: @WillJagy I understand what you have said there but the main confusion I'm having is how can you have $p-1$ numbers be equal to $q+2, q+3, \text{etc}$

Comment: What does "$p-1$ numbers be equal to $q+2,q+3$ etc." mean?

Comment: How many numbers do you get if you start at $q+2$ and end at $q+p$? Well, $p-1$ of them. Same as if you start at 2 and end at $p$. Or start at 1 and end at $p-1$.

Comment: @anon From what I interpreted from the reading, the authors are saying that if you take the numbers $p-1$ then they will equivalent to $q+2, q+3, q+4$ etc. Since, books says exactly "all of the $p-1$ numbers ..." then goes on to show the $q+2, q+3, q+4$ as those numbers.

Comment: Huh? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I guess that didn't help too much. Nevermind. Quite honestly, I don't quite understand what the authors are trying to say in general so, I'm not going to be much help here.

Comment: Will above and Igor below have said exactly what the text is saying: that the numbers $q+2,\cdots,q+p$ are all composite. That is what the text is saying.

Comment: In the quoted passage, the letter $p$ represents a fixed (but unspecified) prime number. You can try substituting $p=7$ and re-read the passage; it should be easier to understand that way. In particular, $7-1=6$, so the authors are saying "all six numbers".

Comment: I understand that they are composite, I just don't understand how you have those numbers be less than $p-1$ when $q$ is equal to the product of primes less than $p$. (If I understand that correctly).

Comment: Obviously the text would not say that $q+2,\cdots,q+p$ are less than $p-1$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely confused now. Can you please re-interpret the passage for me?

Comment: Yes: the numbers $q+2,\cdots,q+p$ (of which there are $p-1$) are composite. That is what the passage says. By the way, [here](http://imgur.com/kqSfSCi) is the original text. (I cannot figure out how could believe the text is saying $q+2$ is less than $p-1$ from this!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's translate the case $p=7$:

> Suppose that $2,3,5,7$ are the primes up to $7$. Then all the numbers up to $7$ are divisible by one of these primes, and therefore, if $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7=210$ all of the six numbers $212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217$ are composite.

Hopefully, the above made sense. The authors are talking about the numbers $212, 213, 214, 215, 216,$ and $217$. There are six numbers listed, because $7-1=6$.

Grammatically, the clause "$p-1$" is being used to modify the plural noun "numbers". The authors are not equating, or comparing, any other variables with $p-1$.

Comment: This makes a $\large{A\,LOT}$ more sense. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

They are saying that

$q+2$ is divisible by $2.$

$q+3$ is divisible by $3.$

$q + 4$ is divisible by $2.$

And so on.

Comment: @anon I didn't read the whole post, I was just doing a slightly naïve question just in case. Reading it, I delete my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n > 0$ then $ n! + 2, .... n! + n$ are all non-prime.  You can create a nonprime streak of arbitrary length using this process.

Answer (score 0):

Psychology is such that sometimes things are hard when they are too simple. Possibly, a slightly stronger theorem + an exercise can help understanding.

Let $\ A\ $ be an arbitrary natural number (positive integer.
Then prove that all consecutive integers:

$$ A\!\cdot\!q+2\quad A\!\cdot\!q+3\quad \ldots
                                \quad A\!\cdot\!q+p $$

are composites -- thus, there are $\,\ p-1\,\ $ different composites which are consecutive integers each time (for each $\ A$).

As another mini-exercise, show that if $\ p>3\ $ then
also

$$ A\!\cdot\!q-2\quad A\!\cdot\!q-3\quad \ldots
                                \quad A\!\cdot\!q-p $$
are all composites.

> WARNING. Without assumption $\ p>3\ $ the above mini-exercise fails (but only a little bit :) ).